# numerical keyboard Ioinc2

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic2

I want a Numerical keyboard to appear on the screen when the alert show
is there a way to do this?

```
showPrompt(message) {
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: "term and condition",
  message:message,

  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'code',
      placeholder: 'Code',
      checked:false,
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can get numeric keyboard. For more info look at [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#advanced).

```
 showPrompt(message) {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "term and condition",
      message:message,

      inputs: [
        {
          type: 'number'
          name: 'code',
          placeholder: 'Code',
          checked:false,
        },
      ]
```